# In Symfony2, how do I change button type from button to submit?

Tags: php, symfony

I try to use Symfony2's (v2.6.1) button widget. I want it to submit the form (meaning the rendered button should have `type="submit"`), but setting in the attr in TWIG doesn't work for me.

```
{{ form_row(form.theButton, {'attr': {'type': 'submit'}, 'label': 'the custom label I need'}) }}
```

I can't believe there is no such setting, so I assume I'm missing something from the docs.

Could anybody spell it out for me?

Comment: Yeah.. Too bad I **assumed** `submit` type gives input, not button..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the `'button'` form field type, use the `'submit'` form field type: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/submit.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `form.submit` instead of `form.theButton`:

```
{{ form_row(form.submit, 'label': 'the custom label I need'}) }}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/submit.html